# How do you properly export/import a NodeJs class and it's respective functions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

**Background:** I am using mysql with nodejs. I expect to use nested queries often, so in an attempt to avoid "callback hell," I have a made a simple class with functions backed by Promises.

**Problem:** After importing my class into my desired file, I attempt to invoke my `query(sql, params){...}` function inside my POST request within the `/login` route, however I get the following error: `TypeError: Database.query is not a function` *Note: All of my code compiles, so there is not a file location issue with my imports. The issue occurs when I am running the program.*

**Code:**

**`Database.js`** : This is what I am exporting into my **`api.js`** file.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

const configuration = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '******',
    database: 'myDB'
}

class Database {
    constructor(configuration) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection(configuration) //
    }

    query(sql, params) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            this.connection.query(sql, params, function(err, result) {
                if(err) return reject(err)
                resolve(result)
            })
        })
    }
}
module.exports = Database
```

**`api.js`** : This is the location for the backend logic of my application.

```
.
.
.
var Database = require('../classes/Database')

//This is the route responsible for invoking my database query
router.post('/login', function(req,res,next) {
    const query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND pass = ?"
    Database.query(query1, [req.body.username, req.body.password])
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.length) {
            if (req.session.username) {
                res.send('You are logged in')
            } else {
                req.session.username = req.body.username
                res.send('You have successfully logged in')
            }
        } else {
            res.send('Incorrect Credentials')
        }
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
 })
```

Comment: `module.exports = new Database` simple 1 word fix in your Database.js file. You simply need to instantiate your object. you can do it in the module or externally, it makes no difference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because basic syntax question, also technically a duplicate of hundreds of similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` is a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions) of `Database` that can be called on an actual `Database` object. The way you call it (`Database.query`), it'd have to be a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) of the class `Database`.

To use `query`, you'll have to initialize `Database` somewhere, e.g. with a `const database = new Database(config);`. Then you could access that object and call `query`: `database.query(...)`.